# not able to upload files in PHP

Tags: php

I'm try to upload file in php but i'am no able to do so. I get success message and my record is also saved in database but my folder does not contain that uploaded file. The images folder is empty.

Please help.

My HTML CODE:

```
if($_FILES['site_logo']['name'] != ''){
            $uploaded_file = $_FILES['site_logo']['name'];
            $exp = explode(".",$uploaded_file);
            $extension = end($exp);
            $allowed_types = array('jpg',"jpeg","png","gif");
            if(in_array($extension,$allowed_types)){

                $path = "images/".$uploaded_file;

                if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['site_logo']['tmp_name'],$path))
                {
                    $_SESSION['upload_success'] = "File Uploaded succesfully"; 
                }
                else
                {
                    $_SESSION['upload_error'] = "Something went wrong, file cannot be uploaded"; 
                }
            }   
            else
            {
                $_SESSION['upload_warning'] = "Please upload appropriate file type"; 
            }
        }   
        else
        {
            $_SESSION['upload_warning'] = "Please upload file"; 
        }
```

Comment: check images folder permission

Comment: do you have enctype="multipart/form-data" in your form? also as vikas said, check the directory permissions

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP File Upload Issues](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9424516/php-file-upload-issues)

Comment: Please post your html code as well.... and this question have been answered in SO please go through previous answers as well

Comment: i get this error :- move_uploaded_file(images/1_jesus-calms-storm@2x.jpg): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\wamp\www\PHPMailer\extras\js\process\site_action.php on line 44

Comment: my folder path is incorrect got the solution but i'm confused. when i pass ../images in <img tag> my image is not visible but when i pass ../images in file upload my file is uploaded successfully...

Answer (score 0):

I think your **$path** is not correct

can you please change

> $path = "./image/".$uploaded_file;

if its not work show me your folder structure

Answer (score 0):

you should use

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["site_logo"]['tmp_name'],$path)
```

instead of

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['site_logo']['tmp_name'],$path).
```